# who has loaded an identity mapped page table?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, 64bit, x86

I want to understand Linux x86_64 's startup steps, after reading some articles and `linux-3.14.65/Documentation/x86/boot.txt`, and almost know that the first instruction to run in `vmlinux` is `startup_x86`, but when I read the comments in `arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S` about `startup_64`:

```
    .text
__HEAD
.code64
.globl startup_64
startup_64:
/*
 * At this point the CPU runs in 64bit mode CS.L = 1 CS.D = 0,
 * and someone has loaded an identity mapped page table
 * for us.  These identity mapped page tables map all of the
 * kernel pages and possibly all of memory.
```

I am still confused by the comment, I don't know who make `CPU runs in 64bit mode` and who `has loaded an identity mapped page table for us`? It is `Grub`? What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startup_64` may be entered by

```
/* The entry point for the PE/COFF executable is efi_pe_entry. */
ENTRY(efi_pe_entry)
...
    movl    BP_code32_start(%esi), %eax
    leaq    startup_64(%rax), %rax
    jmp *%rax
ENDPROC(efi_pe_entry)
```

Alternatively, I believe `handover_entry` inside the `efi_pe_entry` routine may be jumped to directly by a Linux-aware EFI bootloader.  This hybrid approach allows bootloaders to continue providing certain linux-specific features, while at the same time allowing the kernel to use EFI-specific features.  See [The bootstrap process on EFI systems (LWN.net)](https://lwn.net/Articles/632528/).

Finally, `startup_64` may be jumped to from `startup_32`; this happens when the kernel is loaded by a Linux-aware BIOS boot loader.

(Ok, there is one more case.  A 64 bit kernel may have an `efi32_stub_entry` point that then jumps to `startup_32`.  I'm ignoring this.  64-bit kernels on 32-bit EFI is still marked experimental anyway).

Based on the above, I am not sure that `startup_64` is *ever* the first instruction to run in `vmlinux`.  The comment says it could be entered "directly from a 64bit bootloader", but I don't know of any such thing.

In the BIOS case, you can clearly see that `startup_32` is responsible for setting up an initial 64-bit page table ("early 4G boot pagetable"), and of course switching to 64-bit mode a.k.a. "long mode".

In the EFI64 case, the CPU is already in 64-bit mode.  `efi_pe_entry` calls `make_boot_params()` and `efi_main()` in `eboot.c`.   (`handover_entry` just calls `efi_main()`, as in this case the bootloader provides `struct boot_params`).  `eboot.c` does not set up page tables.  Therefore the comment is assuming EFI has at least set up an identity mapping for all the pages of the kernel it loaded (including any [bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) space), which makes sense to me :-).

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_64.S

Answer (score 0):

According to the first bullet in the "Initializing the page table" section of http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbansal/os/lec/l14.html, entry.S is responsible for setting up page tables. And we do indeed find logic in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S that deals with this (" The page tables are set up such that ...").

In https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_64.S, though, we find more references to setting up page tables. Here we see "Build early 4G boot pagetable" and "Enable the boot page tables."

This article provides examples of how to enable paging, including identity paging: https://github.com/littleosbook/littleosbook/blob/master/paging.md. Notice that the example uses control registers cr3, cr4 and cr0, as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register. The entry_64.S and head_64.S files also use these control registers.

Comment: That entry_64.S file you link to does not appear to set up any page tables, but instead deals with system call and irq entry/exit.  I believe the boot loader sets up the page tables these days, unless you are still booting the kernel directly from a floppy disk without a boot loader.